# getting a segmentation fault even after compilation?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

struct Result{
    int reversen;
    unsigned short count;
};

struct Result *myCount(int, int);
int main()
{
    struct Result *result;
    myCount(122333, 2);
    printf("\nReversed integer of 122333: %d", result->reversen);
    printf("\nOccurrence of 2 in 122333: %hu", result->count);  
    return 0;
}

struct Result * myCount(int n, int d)
{
    struct Result * result = (struct  Result *) malloc (sizeof (struct  Result));
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nNo storage space available\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int rev_dig, last_dig, digit,  count = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        last_dig = n % 10;
        rev_dig = rev_dig * 10 + last_dig;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    rev_dig = rev_dig * (-1);   
    result->reversen = rev_dig;

    while (n >= 1)
    {
        digit = n % 10;
        if (digit == d)
            count++;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    result->count = count;  
}
```

trying to reverse an integer value along with change of sign and also finding the occurrence of a digit in the number.

Basically i guess i am doing something wrong with pointers. 
can anyone help me out to figure out where am i going wrong?

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger. This will tell you where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: How do you get a segmentation fault **before** compilation?

Comment: Start by activating warnings (-Wall if gcc). You'll see some interesting things.

Comment: Segmentation faults are by nature a runtime event. They always happen after compilation.

Comment: @iharob with a buggy editor, presumably :)

Comment: @MartinJames Well that's a possible explanation.

Comment: You seem to think that developing software should stop after a compilation is successful.  Sorry, not remotely correct, and the testing/debugging are orders-of-magnitude more difficult than just getting stuff to compile/build.

Comment: @MartinJames To expand upon your point, this is even more true with languages like C because of undefined behavior. Successful compilation is a terrible indicator as to whether or not your program actually functions as inteded.

Answer (score 4):

You never initialize `result` in `main()` and you never return anything from `myCount()`.

Just do this in `main()`

```
result = myCount();
```

remember to check against `NULL`.

And in `myCount()`

```
struct Result * myCount(int n, int d)
{
    struct Result *result;
    int rev_dig;
    int last_dig;
    int digit;
    int count;

    count = 0;
    result = malloc(sizeof (struct  Result));
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL; /* handle the error in the caller function */        
    while (n != 0)
    {
        last_dig = n % 10;
        rev_dig = rev_dig * 10 + last_dig;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    rev_dig = rev_dig * (-1);   
    result->reversen = rev_dig;    
    while (n >= 1)
    {
        digit = n % 10;
        if (digit == d)
            count++;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    result->count = count;
    return result;
}
```

Fixes:

1. Return `NULL` if `malloc()` fails, imitating the behavior of `malloc()`. Functions that return pointers to newly allocated memory usually do this, e.g. `strdup()`.
2. Removed the superflous cast of `malloc()`.
3. Returned `result` at some point.

Not returning a value from a function declared as returning something is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the structure pointer which was never initialized.